# Laravel 5 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

I'm trying to do a `foreach()` inside of one of my controller and I'm running into the error of `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` this is my code

```
$subAdmins = $request->input('subAdmin');

  // Adding subAdmin
  foreach($subAdmins as $subAdmin){
    $linksubAdmin = new LayMinisterEvents;
    $linksubAdmin->user_id = $subAdmin;
    $linksubAdmin->event_id = $recordEvent->id;
    $linksubAdmin->save();
 }
```

This is the data that is getting sent over `'subAdmins' => '5,6'`

```
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argument supplied for 
foreach()', '/home/vagrant/www/project-
api/app/Http/Controllers/EventsController.php', 47, array('request' => 
object(Request), 'response' => object(Response), 'authUser' => 1, 
'recordEvent' => object(Events), 'linkadminLeader' => 
object(AdminEvent), 'subAdmins' => '5,6'))
in EventsController.php (line 47)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, a foreach only works on arrays and arrayables, but it looks like you're giving it a string. You can explode the string and foreach over that:

```
$subAdmins = explode(',', $request->input('subAdmin'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because `'5,6'` is a string not an array Try to "expode it" using `explode`

```
$subAdmins = explode(',', $request->input('subAdmin'));
```

or you can edit your form in view to be considerate as an array input try something like

```
<input name="subAdmin[]" type="text">
```

Comment: I could not do it this way because I'm using laravel as an API so it's getting passed through from angular